# Why the memory isnt getting freed even after using the free() in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
/*This is a linked list program and I have created a following structure:*/

struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *next;
 }

/*And then I create a new node:*/

struct node *t;
t=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
t->data=15;
t->next=NULL;
free(t);
print("%d",t->data);

/*So ,here the printf will still print 15 ,despite of the memory for t being freed.
```

Can someone please help me out.
And if I again print the value for the second time its printing a garbage value. 
PS: I'm using turbo C++ as an IDE.*/

Comment: Your expectation on the behavior of `free()` is probably wrong here. Your `t` node won't just disappear into the void after you free it. You can even access that memory, but doing so ends up in undefined behavior.

Comment: After freeing some memory you are not allowed to access it. The attempt to read it invokes undefined behaviour. Therefore any result can happen.

Comment: Because the compiler can't make the physical memory cells go away. `free` does not tear the RAM memory out of the computer. What makes you think it should?

Comment: Turbo C++ reminds me of those x86 machines from previous millennium that didn't have a MMU at all. The SO could not make memory unaccessible even if it wanted to.